# Password Protect Magento Storeview with a general Login

Tags: php, magento, authentication, magento-1.4

I have a Magento Website with different Storeviews.
One of theese Storeviews is wholesale.

I don't want to let regular people visit this storeview.
So I want a general password protection (htaccess like) with just one user password.

htaccess dosen't work in this case because the storeview is no real directory.

I tried a session based login with redirect like this: http://aktuell.de.selfhtml.org/artikel/php/loginsystem/
In this example I log in and if I use the right usr & pw I get redirected to the normal magento login.
But it seems that this dosen't work with magento, because some how my session gets destroyed or reset.

Does anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/jreinke/magento-require-login

This should do the trick. Its maybe easier to just install this 3rd party extension.

Comment: Tried but not working..probably because m using 1.9.2.2

Answer (score 2):

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-groups-catalog2-4585.html

is another choice. It's also hide category in frontend.

**Updated**
You change settings of Groups Catalog 2 like this:

1. In Default Scope: Disable Module
2. Choose scope of store you want to hide unauthorized users, change settings like attached image.
   [image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers! 

I already managed to redirect, all customer in the wholesale storeview to the login page. (Even though I'll try this extensions because they are more elegant.)

But I want only customers to be able using the storeview 'wholesale', when they have the general login for the wholesale area.

So first the general login, then login as a customer, or create the account.

how can this best be achieved?

Comment: thanks, i already stumbled upon this extension.
I also use this extension: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/eu-vat-grouper.html
to auto assing customer to groups.

But the Problem is, even if they have a valid tax id, I don't want all of them to see the wholesale area.
Only a selected few shell have access.